# sqlalchemy `A transaction is already begun on this Session` error when beginning transaction in fastapi app

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, fastapi

In my fastapi app I'm adding `db_session` to `request.state` within middleware like below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware


# https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio.create_async_engine
engine = create_async_engine("<my postgres url>", future=True, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=True)


# https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker.__init__
AsyncSessionFactory = async_sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False, future=True, class_=AsyncSession)


class AddDBSessionToRequest(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        async with AsyncSessionFactory() as db_session:
            try:
                request.state.db_session = db_session
                print(f"Middleware transaction status: {db_session.in_transaction()}")  # prints False
                response = await call_next(request)
            except SQLAlchemyError:
                logger.exception("SQLAlchemy error when processing '%s %s'", request.method, request.url)
                response = Response("Internal server error", status_code=500)
        return response

middleware = [
    Middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=get_settings().cors_origins,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    ),
    Middleware(TrustedHostMiddleware, allowed_hosts=get_settings().allowed_hosts),
    Middleware(MeasureRequestProcessingTime),
    Middleware(AddDBSessionToRequest),
]


app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)

@app.post("/test")
async def test_view(request: Request):
    db_session = request.state.db_session
    print(f"view transaction status: {db_session.in_transaction()}")  # prints True
    async with db_session.begin():
        # do something
        pass
```

But above fails with error message: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun on this Session.`

I'm trying to understand where is the transaction started or what is starting it...

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 94, in receive
    return self.receive_nowait()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 89, in receive_nowait
    raise WouldBlock
anyio.WouldBlock

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 78, in call_next
    message = await recv_stream.receive()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 114, in receive
    raise EndOfStream
anyio.EndOfStream

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test/app.py", in dispatch
    response = await call_next(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 84, in call_next
    raise app_exc
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 70, in coro
    await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/test/app.py", in test_view
    async with db_session.begin():
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/base.py", line 127, in __aenter__
    return await self.start(is_ctxmanager=True)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 1769, in start
    await greenlet_spawn(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 179, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1811, in begin
    raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A transaction is already begun on this Session.
```

I tested with plain async code like below, which is not showing that error:

```py
# continuation of first example

import asyncio


async def another_test():
    async with AsyncSessionFactory() as db_session:
        async with db_session.begin():
            # do something
            pass

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(another_test())
```

I only get that sqlalchemy error when running in fastapi, but not when running in plain async function. Please help me understand why is sqlalchemy throwing error in one case but not in the other.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277841/how-do-i-prevent-sqlalchemy-from-creating-a-transaction-on-select) which suggests using `begin_nested` instead of `begin`... and this is probably what I will do.

I also found [this github thread](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/6921) where `autobegin` arg is mentioned. Though I will stick with `begin_nested`.

Comment: Fails where?  On which line?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I added full stack trace to the question

Comment: Unless you have auto-commit turned on, every SELECT opens a new transaction.  SQLAlchemy is probably doing them behind the scenes.